# Mkdir not working on altervista but in xampp

Tags: php

I tried using the `mkdir` function in `xampp` and it all works regularly setting the local path `C:/XAMPP/htdocs...`

Now, I loaded it all on altervista indicating instead of `C:/XAMPP/htdocs...` the address of the site, but it does not create anything.

Comment: When you want do to some debugging, put a `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` on the very beginning of your script. What's the error(s) that you see? Also: we aren't omniscient. Show us some code.

Comment: It does not leave any error

Comment: please show us the mkdir command and the full value that it is using.